# Fetch only a part of the filename from path

Tags: unix

I have a folder structure like
/folder1/folder2/logs/my_sample_log_.txt

I need only my_sample_log

Could anyone of you please help me ?
I have been struggling with this.

Comment: Which shell are you using? can you print what is under `echo $SHELL` ?

Answer (score 0):

use [basename](https://ss64.com/bash/basename.html) command :

```
name=$(basename "/folder1/folder2/logs/my_sample_log_.txt" .txt | sed 's/_$//' )
```

or simply :

```
name=$(basename "/folder1/folder2/logs/my_sample_log_.txt" _.txt  )
```

Comment: I need to exclude the last underscore as well